# Automate hyperlink to send variables to webform

Tags: nodes, webforms

Here's the background for what I'm tring to accomplish:

- I am using Webform 6.x-3.11 and have a generic sign-up form located at “/project-sign-up."
- The webform has a hidden field with its default value set to "%get[project-title]."
- I have a custom Content-type called `Project` that holds data specific to various community outreach projects.

What I am trying to do is displaying a link at the bottom of each "Project" page saying "SIGN UP!" with the "href" pointing to "/project-sign-up?project=[project-title]." However, I cannot figure out how to create the link through the CCK fields of the content type. I have also tried creating a node attachment through Views UI (views_attach) to append a link (with its output rewritten) to the "Project" node, but to no avail.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing it in Drupal 6 then `hook_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3, $a4)` is to alter node object for additional information.

```
function custom_module_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3, $a4){
  if ($op == 'view' && $node->type == 'project') {
    $node->content['project_link'] = array(
      '#value' => l('Sign Up', 'node/[id]', array('query' => "project=" . $node->title)),
      '#weight' => 100,
    );      
  }
}
```

Comment: hi shoaib, and thanx for the reply. I'm newish to Drupal, so would I be right in assuming that this function goes into my `template.php` file?

Comment: This will go into a custom module. Here is guide about that. [http://drupal.org/node/416986]. You just need to create a directory in your modules directory. choose a unique name for your module. create two files (.info and .module) .info will contain few information about your module see examples in other modules you might be using. Then put the given code in .module file. Do not forget to replace your module name with 'custom_module' in function name.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you Shoaib, that's just what I was looking for!

Comment: On a side note (for my future reference) do you know of any way to attach an existing webform to a node type?  This was my first approach (using nodereference URL) but this failed, and I can't imagine that this hasn't been done before.

Comment: What is your problem? What are you doing with node reference and what is failing?

Comment: I have an existing webform for these project sign-ups, and initially created a nodereference CCK Field in the `Project` content-type. I can't remeber exactly what I did thru Views UI and using ViewsAttch, but everytime I clicked on the SIGN UP link, it took me to a 'Create new Webform' page...I instead wanted it to go to an existing webform with one of the fields pre-poulated thru the nodereference. Not to deviate from the original question, but is this possible?

Comment: I have just update the answer for passing project title to url, after this your half work is finished. For the next step to pre-populate the field you will have to focus on hook_form_alter. In this hook you will edit the form's field for #default_value, most probably you want to populate title.

Comment: @Shalan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/912/discussion-between-shoaib-nawaz-and-shalan)